# Error StringIndexOutOfBoundsException when running GWT application on Tomcat

Tags: java, exception, gwt, tomcat

I am getting the following error when running my GWT application on Tomcat.
When running it on Jetty it works fine.
I do not use the `charAt` function in my code.

How can I trace down this error?

```
SEVERE: Unexpected error
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
        at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.gwt.autobean.server.impl.JsonSplittable.create(JsonSplitta
ble.java:35)
        at com.google.gwt.autobean.shared.impl.StringQuoter.split(StringQuoter.j
ava:35)
        at com.google.gwt.autobean.shared.AutoBeanCodex.decode(AutoBeanCodex.jav
a:520)
        at com.google.gwt.requestfactory.server.SimpleRequestProcessor.process(S
impleRequestProcessor.java:121)
        at com.google.gwt.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryServlet.doPost(Req
uestFactoryServlet.java:118)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV
alve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV
alve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Authentica
torBase.java:470)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j
ava:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.j
ava:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVal
ve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav
a:298)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcesso
r.java:864)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.pr
ocess(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:16
65)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: its not your code but its from google .. http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/autobean/server/impl/JsonSplittable.java?r=9189. I wonder how its working on Jetty ... is there any parameter you are not passing to tomcat ? Or may be you are passing the parameter but empty and non null --> "".

Comment: @hanumant: The parameters are the same for Jetty and Tomcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works after cleaning Tomcat's work folder.

Answer (score 1):

This error means your servlet is receiving an empty request body (no length, empty string). There's probably something wrong in your Tomcat setup that strips the request body before it reaches your servlet. It's hard to tell, and I don't Tomcat much.